# "Perfectly" rectangular dynamic text

Tags: css, dynamic, text, width, containers

Is it possible to shorten a container (preferably div) so that the dynamically inserted text within becomes a "perfect" rectangle without increasing the height?

```
<div style="width:800px;">
<div>I'd like these words to look like below, but I'd like to "automatically" set it with a few lines of CSS rather than with jQuery or some other computationally intensive alternative.</div>
</div>
<br>
<div style="width:800px;">
<div style="width:530px;">I'd like these words to look like below, but I'd like to "automatically" set it with a few lines of CSS rather than with jQuery or some other computationally intensive alternative.</div>
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q7gcb/

I'd like to do this with a single CSS setting if possible, but I can't find one.  I'd also like to avoid a loop in javascript to do this because I have to do this to a lot of divs, and I don't want performance to suffer.

white-space doesn't seem to help unless if I'm using it wrong.

Many thanks in advance!

**text-align:justify;**

By itself doesn't help: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7gcb/4/

**max-width + text-align:justify;**

Doesn't work either: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7gcb/5/

Comment: Set a max width, then justify the text?

Comment: I guess you mean something other than text-align:justify?

Comment: I believe this might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205109/justify-text-to-fill-a-div

Comment: You can't manually set it. For example in IE9, or in Chrome on a Mac, your `<div style="width:530px;">` example text is three lines long, not two (due to different text rendering). I think you need JavaScript.

Comment: I appreciate your help and note.  Already tried javascript.  It makes my page choppy.  Lots of dynamic divs.

Comment: Well, if I understand correctly what you're trying to do, it can't be done with pure CSS. You need JavaScript. Perhaps your implementation can be optimised?

Comment: Damn.  I tried geometrically decaying increments of shortening the width until the height increased.  It got the job done, but it chopped the hell out of my page.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy Try my solution, I believe it is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what you are looking for can be found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205109/justify-text-to-fill-a-div)

"In DTP and word processing applications, this option is known as 'force justify'. Unfortunately, this is not an option in CSS."

Answer (score 1):

```
div {text-align: justify;}​
```

And you should set width value as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `max-width` and `text-align` to `justify`.

```
div {
    max-width: 500px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7gcb/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

HTML

```
<div style="width:800px;">
<div>I'd like these words to look like below, but I'd like to "automatically" set it with a few lines of CSS rather than with jQuery or some other computationally intensive alternative.</div>
</div>
<br>
<div style="width:800px;">
<div style="width:530px;">I'd like these words to look like below, but I'd like to "automatically" set it with a few lines of CSS rather than with jQuery or some other computationally intensive alternative.</div>
</div>
<br>
<div style="width:800px;">
<div class="justify">I'd like these words to look like below, but I'd like to "automatically" set it with a few lines of CSS rather than with jQuery or some other computationally intensive alternative.</div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.justify{
    text-align: justify;
    text-align-last: justify;
}

.justify:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q7gcb/7/

Comment: I appreciate your creativity, but I'd rather shorten the div so that it looks like the 530px example.  Thanks for trying!