# Justification of text in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there way to force the justification of text using CSS to one line? For example:

```
I want to justify this text
like                   this
ButIdon'tmindifitsquashesit
```

I don't need people to tell me that it's a bad idea to justify text in web pages (I have a manual line spacing and hyphenation algorithm to assist), but I'm just wondering if there's a solution, CSS or JavaScript, to handle this.

---

Sorry, wasn't very clear with my question: Each line is in a separate `div` element, e.g.:

```
<div>I want to justify this text</div>
<div>like this</div>
<div>But I don't mind if it squashes it</div>
```

I know about `text-align: justify` but it doesn't solve my problem — it justifies according to how the browser wants to, not by the each line I have. This may result in inappropriate line breaking or falling short of the right edge.

Comment: You mean text-align:justify; or?

Comment: Sorry, didn't explain my question very well.

Comment: What are you using to help you make justified text look ok?

Comment: @dylanfm: My own implementation of Knuth-Plass line-breaking.

Comment: @rfw Do those DIV elements have a fixed width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot `justify` single lines of text.

However, you can hack together something that may work for you.

```
div{width:300px; 
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:justify; text-justify: newspaper;
}

div:after{
    content: " &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    line-height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/zX9x5/1/

This only works if you are okay with an extra blank line under the content.

*borders just for example to see spacing, etc.*

H/T to [@thirtydot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405015/thirtydot) for the idea: [Justify the last line of a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771304/justify-the-last-line-of-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

You might try

```
text-align: justify;
```

in your CSS :-)

Comment: Well, if you're able to define a common width for all your divs, which you should be, if you already process the content, you can still go with text-align, just for each separate div.

Comment: Doesn't work -- I have `text-align: justify; width: 1000px;` and it is still left-justified.