# Justify text with final line left-aligned

Tags: html, css

I've got a client who wants a paragraph of text to appear justified and rather than having the last line flush left, they want it centered. I haven't come up with a way to do this yet that will properly scale if the page is resized by the user. Am I going to have to resort to some kind of javascript hack? I just feel like this is the sort of problem that I should be able to solve with CSS alone.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771304/justify-the-last-line-of-a-div

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 has a [text-align-last property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-align-last0) that you might find useful.  On the other hand, using a different [text-justify method](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-justify0) might be preferred.

Comment: I tried out css3's text-align-last property already, do you know if any browsers actually support it? As far as I can tell Chrome, Firefox, and Safari don't which, sadly makes it useless.

Comment: @NSU Internet Explorer supports both properties.

Comment: Yeah, just found out the same myself. Sadly, _only_ IE supports text-align-last. I'll probably do some weird hack with nonbreaking spaces and see how well that works.