# How can I justify the text placed on multiple lines and columns

Tags: css, text-align

I am wondeing how can I justify some text in an HTML document in the following manner:

**Original Text:**

```
............     ..........
.......          ......
```

**Result Expected:**

```
............     . . ........
. . . . . ..     .  . . . . .
```

I've been thinking and searching about a solution but I couldn't get anywhere.

Please help.

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, the columns and the rows should remain completely separate.

Comment: There are many existing questions about text justification, and the simplest answer `text-align: justify` can be found in many of them. Proper justification is a rather complicated issue, and you should clarify what the goal is. In particularly, from the example, it seems that the last line should be justified, too. Is that right?

Comment: That's right, the longest column in any row should be taken as the largest one and the rest should be stretched based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can justify text with `text-align: justify`, but this tends to cause typographically poor results. You can improve the situation by using hyphenation (in CSS or with JavaScript). On IE, you can additionally use `text-justify: newspaper`, which tends to improve the result.

Regarding the last line of a paragraph or other block, which seems to be the issue here, you can add

```
-moz-text-align-last: justify;
text-align-last: justify;
```

On IE and Firefox, this makes the last line justified. But you may not like the result. If the last line has just a little text, compared with the column width, it will have huge gaps between words and/or letters.

The division of text into columns is a separate issues and has many possible approaches, depending on context and design preferences.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your text has been placed in columns either as separate divs or the `css-columns` attribute, setting `text-align: justify;` should do the trick. Without seeing the markup involved I cannot help further.

EDIT: Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771304/justify-the-last-line-of-a-div) and the top answer. I hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

Just put this lines on each column and line:

```
text-align:justify;
text-justify:inter-word;
```

Comment: Bonus points for using [text-justify](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-justify), but you should really explain your answer, not just give a piece of code.

Comment: I can't see how I can use this. <div style="text-align:justify; text-justify:inter-word;">
............     ..........<br />
.......          ......
</div> not working.