# In colorbox title, can the width be controlled?

Tags: css, colors, colorbox

I need to have some text below the image, but it has to be justified and full width from left to right. In order to do this I think I have to put a width on the title? I tried putting width:100% in the CSS, but it seems to ignore it.
Anyone have any ideas I can try?

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to justify a one-line element. If so, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771304/justify-the-last-line-of-a-div) might help you.

Comment: I tried that advice and unfortunately it didn't work for me. Shouldn't I somehow add a width value? Since colorbox is dynamic according to the image size, I don't know how that's possible. I tried to make it width: 100% but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Did you try styling #cboxTitle?