# How do you align elements to the right with display inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I have two div tags for my footer. I want one to be on the left of the page and one on the right. I'm using display:inline-block for both divs to be on the same line but Im not able to make them float.

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="phone">
        <img id="pIcon" src="img/phone_icon.png" alt="Phone icon" />  
        <p id="pValue"> # </p>
    </div>
    <div id="email">
       <img id="eIcon" src="img/email_icon.png" alt="Email icon" />
       <p id="eValue"> # </p>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end of footer -->


#footer {
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:rgba(102,51,255,1);
}

#email {

    background-color:rgba(255,255,0,1);}

#phone, #email {
    display:inline-block;
    width:45%;
}

#pIcon, #pValue {
    display:inline-block;
}

#eValue, #eIcon {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771304/justify-the-last-line-of-a-div you have two divs with display-inline, so you can align justify that line with a little trick, then the first div will be on the left and the second div will be on the right

Answer (score 2):

You need `text-align` property. For the one you want left to be `left` and right to be `right`

```
#phone, #email {
    display:inline-block;
    width:45%;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle; //If you need vertical middle alignment
}
#email {
    text-align: right;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vH6bt/)</kbd>

Comment: Nice one thanks! i tried text-align before but it eems the vertical-align did the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="footer">
    <p id="phone">
        <img id="pIcon" src="img/phone_icon.png" alt="Phone icon" />#</p>
    <p id="email">
        <img id="eIcon" src="img/email_icon.png" alt="Email icon" />#</p>
</div>

#footer {
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:rgba(102, 51, 255, 1);
}
#email {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
}
#phone {
    display:inline-block;
}
#eIcon, #pIcon {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not able to float them because of white spaces. White space counts if you're using `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`.

If you want to reach desired layout with `display: inline-block;` you have to change you HTML to this ugly (it is not a formatting error!):

```
<div id="footer"><div id="phone">
    <img id="pIcon" src="img/phone_icon.png" alt="Phone icon" />  
    <p id="pValue"> # </p>
</div><div id="email">
   <img id="eIcon" src="img/email_icon.png" alt="Email icon" />
   <p id="eValue"> # </p>
</div></div> <!-- end of footer -->
```

I prefer much cleaner solution, using float and clear properties.

*HTML*

```
<div id="footer" class="clearfix">
    <div id="phone">
        <img id="pIcon" src="img/phone_icon.png" alt="Phone icon" />
        <p id="pValue">#</p>
    </div>
    <div id="email">
        <img id="eIcon" src="img/email_icon.png" alt="Email icon" />
        <p id="eValue">#</p>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end of footer -->
```

*CSS*

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

#footer {
    bottom:0;
    background-color:rgba(102, 51, 255, 1);
}
#email {
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
}
#phone, #email {
    float: left;
    width:50%;
}
#pIcon, #pValue {
    display:inline-block;
}
#eValue, #eIcon {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ee3ag/). More info about a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) CSS trick is [here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Answer (score -2):

## email {

background-color:rgba(255,255,0,1);
**float:right;**
}

Comment: I wanted to avoid using float as the email logo and address shift up