# AngularJS not respecting CSS styles when rendering LIs in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css, templates

I decided to implement a set of round circles connected by a line as outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513784/css3-responsive-circles-connected-by-a-line). Everything seems to work fine in static HTML, but when I make it dynamic using Angular's ng-repeat, the circles justify left. It can be clearly illustrated by the following jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1ho1zz59/

```
<ul class="progress-rnd">
    <li ng-repeat="step in steps">
      {{step.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Based on that I just have two questions:

1. Why is this happening?
2. And how do I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `text-align: justify;` works on html that has a space in it differently than what angular generates (`li` tags are followed by commented html and the next tag). This directive should work, [example](https://jsfiddle.net/1ho1zz59/4/):

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
angular.module('testApp')
.directive('addASpaceBetween', [function () {
        'use strict';
        return function (scope, element) {
            element.after(' ');
        }
    }
]);
```

and adding it to the repeat `ng-repeat="step in steps" data-add-a-space-between`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Need to brush up my html/css skills.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because in Html, when you have elements inline-block, you have whitespace between them, in this case your LI tags. You can fix it by creating a real distance between them in CSS, and not relying on HTML.

Solution
http://jsbin.com/qumawex/edit?css,output