# CSS, horizontal distribution + horizontal+vertical centered text

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items, DIVs that I want to look like large squares, that I want to appear in line and centered on my page, distributed horizontally, and with the text inside each of the DIVs centered both vertically and horizontally.

In other words, something like this with three items:

```
|
|   [........]        [........]        [..Even..]   |
|   [..Text..]        [MoreText]        [..More..]   |   
|   [........]        [........]        [..Text..]   | <- page border   

    <--------------fixed-total-width------------->
```

Same with a fourth item inserted:

```
|
|   [........]  [........]  [........]  [..Even..]   |
|   [..Text..]  [MoreText]  [........]  [..More..]   |   
|   [........]  [........]  [........]  [..Text..]   | <- page border   

    <--------------fixed-total-width------------->
```

My constraints:

- The overall width (DIVs + interspace) is fixed
- The size of each DIV is fixed
- The number of DIVs is dynamic
- The text content is dynamic
- No Javascript, only HTML and CSS

I have used many combinations of display, align and div structures... The items are either not distributed properly, or the text is not vertically centered, or other glitches appear...

All suggestions are welcome!

Thanks! RS

--

Current CSS:

```css
.container { background-color:#FFFFFF; width:900px; margin:10px auto; }
.container .item { display:table-cell; text-align:center; width:160px; height:160px; }
.container .textitem { width:160px; height:160px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;
                       text-align:center; background-color:#CCCCCC; }
```

Current HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="item"> <div class="textitem">Text</div> </div>
 <div class="item"> <div class="textitem">MoreText</div> </div>
 <div class="item"> <div class="textitem">Even more text</div> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not use a <table>?

Comment: Is the HTML mutable? Or must we stick with your structure?

Comment: @aelgoa because the CSS and layout vary depending on the viewing device. Horizontal on computer, vertical on mobile.

Comment: @HerrSerker Yes HTML is mutable. If you can help me get rid of the textitem inside the item, it's even better ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS flexbox layout is designed to solve the requirements you're describing:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sh2D2/4/

```
.container {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    width:450px;
    height: 450px;
    margin:10px auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container .item {

}

.container .textitem {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice!
I initially wanted the first and last items to touch the left and right borders of the container, but I can deal with a small margin. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I added one more level of `div`s which has `display:block` and `margin: auto`
See in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98zte/)

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="itemblock">
            <div class="textitem">Text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="itemblock">
            <div class="textitem">MoreText</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="itemblock">
            <div class="textitem">Even more text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.container {
    background-color:#0FFFFF;
    width:900px;
    margin:10px auto;
    display: table;
}
.container .item {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
}
.container .itemblock {
    display:block;
    margin: auto;
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
}
.container .textitem {
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Strangely enough, the first blocks are all attached to the bottom of the container, and the last block is attached to the top line... (on FF at least)

Answer (score 0):

You can mix [Centering in the unknown](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) (*) and [Justify the last line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771304/justify-the-last-line-of-a-div)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pML4m/)

```
.container {
    width:900px;
    margin:10px auto;
    text-align: justify;
}
.container:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.container > .item {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
.container > .item:before, .container .textitem {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.container > .item:before {
    height: 100%;
    content:'';
}
```

<sub>(*) Not really necessary in this case, since you know the sizes</sub>

Comment: I tried that before too, but that only works if you have only one line of text (otherwise boxes start moving up and down)

Comment: @aresando Not sure what you mean. Can you link a demo?

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/6sf2L (the only difference with yours is the reduced box and container sizes, and longer text). On FF, the grey boxes move up when more text is inserted.

Comment: @aresando The problem is that spaces in the HTML aren't discarded. Can be fixed with `font-size: 0`. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6sf2L/1/)