# justify one line of html text to fill an entire line?

Tags: html, justify, text-justify

I have a navigation bar with links inside and its around the height I'd like it right now but I want the buttons to be evenly spaced but `text-align:justify;` isn't working.
I'm I doing something wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/xuEY6/

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xuEY6/1/?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Justify the last line of a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771304/justify-the-last-line-of-a-div)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add

```css
#navigation:after { /* Justify last line */
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
#navigation { /* Fix added space */
    height: 1.15em;
    line-height: 1.15;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xuEY6/2/)

Comment: Thanks, but why the heck does this work? do the a elements just need something to scale against?

Comment: @SpencerKillen `text-align: justify` doesn't justify the last line. Then, you can add a pseudo-element with `width:100%` which will fall to the next line, so the line you want to justify won't be the last one and it will be justified.

Answer (score 11):

If you add:

```
text-align-last:justify;
```

to the #navigation line you will get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If you are okay without Safari support (as of 2021), there is now a native solution to this, the [`text-align-last`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last) property:

```css
text-align-last: justify;
```

Apply this to any text and its last (or only) line will be justified, while the regular `text-align` property affects all lines except the last (or none if it's only one line).

This is supported in all major browsers except Safari. Chrome 47+, Edge 12+, Firefox 49+, and Opera. Even IE 5.5+ supports it(!), but `text-align: justify;` must also be set to work.

Safari has a [bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=76173) to track its status, however it has been the better part of a decade without any updates so Apple really ought to step up its game soon. The bug is marked as "RESOLVED FIXED" but that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

your links need to have `width` to fill the line. specify the with as a `%` to fill the line

take a look at this http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified