# Image to the left from a justified text

Tags: html, css, justify

I’m trying to align a logo’s image and text. I cannot justify the second line to the width of the block. Here is the expected result:

[image: Logo to the left from two lines reading “Build Home” and “Industrial theme”]

I tried this:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,500); 
h1 {
    line-height:30px;
    font-size:30px;
    background:#eee;
    color: #333333;
    }

h2 {
    line-height:10px;
    font-size:12px;
    background:#eee;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:  #434343;
    }

img#logo {
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    float:left;
    }
#logo_text{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    width: 230px; 
    }
#logo_text h2{
    text-align: justify;
    }
```

```html
<img id="logo" src="http://placehold.it/52x36">
<div id="logo_text">
    <h1>Build Home</h1>
    <h2>Industrial theme</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [`text-align-last`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-align-last) property in CSS3 that [has not gained wide adoption in the browsers yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last#Browser_compatibility). Therefore you need to set [prefixed versions](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/text/textalignlast.html) of the property, too, and pray everything works.

Also your image has not only force-justified last line, but changed kerning, too. CSS3 has [`text-justify: distribute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#distribute) to evenly distribute the space from the end of the line among both the inter-word and inter-letter space. Sadly, it’s [almost unimplemented](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-justify.asp)<sup>1</sup> as of today (March 2015). Only [MSIE implements it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531172.aspx). For the time being, you need to resort to the usual method of influencing the kerning: the `letter-spacing` property. Setting `letter-spacing: 0.5ex` should do the job.

<sup><sup>1</sup> I cannot find any better source, sorry for W3Schools link. [QuirksMode has only a test.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/text/textjustify.html)</sup>

Another thing that breaks your example is that `h1` and `h2` have margins. You can set `margin: 0`, or better use `div`s, because the texts have just presentational meaning. I’ll replace `h1` with `div.first` and `h2` with `div.second`.

The image is better displayed as background of the `#logo_text`; you just need to reserve enough space for it in the `padding-left` of `#logo_text`. Since `#logo_text` now contains the image, I’ll rename it to `#logo`.

And finally, to get rid of the fragile fixed width setting, both the `#logo` and `.first` should have [`display: inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display). You can always wrap it in another `div` if you don’t like how inline blocks interact with outside elements.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,500); 
#logo {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    padding-left: 62px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/52x36) 0 50% no-repeat;
    }
#logo, #logo .first {
    display: inline-block;
    }
#logo .first {
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: #eee;
    color: #333333;
    }
#logo .second {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #eee;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #434343;
    text-align: justify;
    -moz-text-align-last: justify;
    -webkit-text-align-last: justify;
    -ms-text-align-last: justify;
    -o-text-align-last: justify;
    text-align-last: justify;
    -moz-text-justify: distribute;
    -webkit-text-justify: distribute;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute;
    -o-text-justify: distribute;
    text-justify: distribute;
    letter-spacing: 0.5ex; /* HACK: Remove once text-justify is supported. */
    }
.outline {
    margin-top: 1em;
    }
.outline * {
    outline: 1px dotted;
    }
.outline #logo .first {
    outline-color: red;
    }
.outline #logo .second {
    outline-color: green;
    }
.outline #logo {
    outline-color: blue;
    }
.outline #logo .first::after, .outline #logo .second::after {
    outline: 1px dotted #cad;
    }
```

```html
<div id="logo">
    <div class="first">Build Home</div>
    <div class="second">Industrial theme</div>
</div>

<div class="outline">
<div id="logo">
    <div class="first">Build Home</div>
    <div class="second">Industrial theme</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Without CSS3 properties, there is a <del>nasty hack</del> work-around using empty `:after` pseudo-element (called `::after` in CSS3) with `display: inline-block` and `width: 100%`. It forms a new line in the corresponding element and thus lest the originally last line be justified.

The problem is that you get an empty line at the end of the corresponding element. When applying this hack to paragraphs of real text, it doesn’t matter that much, because you usually use margin to create the space anyway. Here, it is a deal-breaker.

There are at least two ways to work-around it:

- Set absolute height to `.second. Here`height: 1em`.
- Set negative word spacing of at least size of a space. Here `word-spacing: -1em`.

For both the trick with `::after` and its improvement using `word-spacing`, full credit goes to Vjeux:

- http://blog.vjeux.com/2011/css/css-one-line-justify.html
- http://blog.vjeux.com/2012/css/css-displaying-a-justified-line-of-text.html

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,500); 
#logo {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    padding-left: 62px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/52x36) 0 50% no-repeat;
    }
#logo, #logo .first {
    display: inline-block;
    }
#logo .first {
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: #eee;
    color: #333333;
    }
#logo .second {
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #eee;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #434343;
    letter-spacing: 0.5ex; /* HACK: Remove once text-justify is supported. */
    }
#logo .second::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    }
.with_height #logo .second {
    height: 1em;
    }
.with_word_spacing #logo .second {
    word-spacing: -1em;
    }
.outline {
    margin-top: 1em;
    }
.outline * {
    outline: 1px dotted;
    }
.outline #logo .first {
    outline-color: red;
    }
.outline #logo .second {
    outline-color: green;
    }
.outline #logo {
    outline-color: blue;
    }
.outline #logo .first::after, .outline #logo .second::after {
    outline: 1px dotted #cad;
    }
```

```html
<div id="logo">
    <div class="first">Build Home</div>
    <div class="second">Industrial theme</div>
</div>
<div id="logo" class="with_height">
    <div class="first">Build Home</div>
    <div class="second" style="height:1em">Industrial theme</div>
</div>
<div id="logo" class="with_word_spacing">
    <div class="first">Build Home</div>
    <div class="second" style="height:1em">Industrial theme</div>
</div>

<div class="outline">
<div id="logo" class="with_height">
    <div class="first">Build Home</div>
    <div class="second" style="height:1em">Industrial theme</div>
</div>
<div id="logo" class="with_height">
    <div class="first">Build Home</div>
    <div class="second" style="height:1em">Industrial theme</div>
</div>
<div id="logo" class="with_word_spacing">
    <div class="first">Build Home</div>
    <div class="second" style="height:1em">Industrial theme</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Later I found this related question: [Justify the last line of a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4771304/2157640)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of justify

```
#logo_text h2{
  text-align: center;
 }
 #logo_text h1{
  padding: 3px 0px;
 }
```