# Justify text aligned to the right, punctuation incorrect

Tags: css

I need to make the text justified and the last line aligned to the right, here's what I've done:
CSS:

```
p{
    text-align:justify;
    direction:rtl;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tincidunt gravida efficitur. Mauris auctor, lacus quis maximus viverra, arcu leo posuere magna, eget convallis lectus arcu vel diam. Nam sed diam eu ligula faucibus aliquam non eget tellus. Integer suscipit interdum enim, eu feugiat lectus cursus ac. Nunc ipsum lacus, rutrum eu neque in, ornare tristique nulla. Aenean convallis, metus non hendrerit convallis, magna tortor consequat velit, in laoreet tortor felis eu purus. Vestibulum venenatis, neque a hendrerit tristique, tellus urna convallis orci, ac sagittis magna nisl at est.</p>

<p>Duis dapibus lorem et tincidunt rutrum. Aliquam id ante venenatis massa egestas egestas. Quisque purus mauris, congue vitae nunc ac, vulputate vehicula massa. In in ullamcorper tortor, eu euismod felis. Donec suscipit pellentesque velit, in auctor mauris gravida id. Nunc at iaculis arcu. Etiam sed nibh eu urna auctor ullamcorper et non odio. Morbi vel augue id libero sollicitudin commodo at a ex. Proin fermentum augue at mattis consequat. Curabitur consectetur, nisi semper accumsan pellentesque, mi sapien maximus erat, eu venenatis dolor ipsum euismod nisi. Donec ut odio leo.</p>
```

JSFIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/u1nbg939/1/
The problem is that it's messing up with the last line punctuation, it's going to the beginning of the line. 
Any alternative (a cross browser one)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Justify the last line of a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771304/justify-the-last-line-of-a-div)

Comment: You should not misuse the `direction` property for styling.

Comment: Are you open to the use of jQuery

Comment: @Wavemaster, https://jsfiddle.net/u1nbg939/3/, the answer from the question doesn't work.

Comment: @SleekGeek well, as a last resort, yes.

Comment: use Pseudo-selector p::last-line {text-align : right;}

Comment: @NeerajVerma, it didn't worked :( I guess that is because the tag p is treated all as a single line.

Comment: probably you have your reasons but I will always recomend to never use justify texts on web, and specially if a responsive one. At least till browsers starts using hyphenate texts in a decent way (which will take quite a long time I'm afraid)

Comment: try p::first-line {color : red;} if it works for first line then the problem will be something else. I don't think css treat the whole paragraph as single line.

Comment: @NeerajVerma, true, the first line got red, but when using the last-line selector, it doesn't select the last line, https://jsfiddle.net/u1nbg939/4/