# Justifying a single line breaks the line before the last word in IE when last word is followed by a hyphen

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, justify

I have the following code:

```css
.clJustify {
  width: 400px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: justify;
}
.clJustify:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Justify Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p class="clJustify">This is text that should be jus-</p>
  <p class="clJustify">tified and also hyphenated.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Please don’t ask me why I want to do this. :-)

My problem is: In FF and Chrome this results in two lines of text that fill the space of the `<p>`. But IE breaks the first line before the “jus-” and puts it into a separate line. A line without a hyphen will be displayed as expected, it is the hyphen at the end that confuses IE, it seems.

Here is a screenshot from Internet Explorer:

[image: Screenshot from IE]

And here is a screenshot from Firefox:

[image: Screenshot from FF]

Any ideas how I could prevent IE from breaking the line? The suggested answers to older posts don't address the problem of the *hyphen*.

Comment: Okay, I am not asking you why you wanna do this, but do you wanna do this only this way?

Comment: If there is another way of justifying a single line, I will be grateful to know it.

Comment: Justify a single line? I Have an idea. Try `text-align-last`, writing you an answer with a snippet.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771304/justify-the-last-line-of-a-div

Comment: You can try using different kinds of dashes ( U+2010 to U+2015) and see if they have the same quirks...

Comment: Thanks @MrLister, I'll try this.

Comment: @MrLister, thanks for this suggestion. `&#x2010;` works in a way, as it is not treated as a hyphen, but unfortunately in the font I am using it looks different from other hyphens in the text. 
`&#x2013;` produces a different quirk, appart from being way too long: in this case the line is broken not before the last word, but before the dash.

Answer (score 1):

Try `text-align-last` and `-ms-text-align-last`, this works in IE:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Justify Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .clJustify{
        width: 400px;
        height: 1.5em;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border: 1px solid red;
        text-align: justify;
        -ms-text-align-last: justify;
        text-align-last: justify;
      }
      .clJustify:after{
        content: " ";
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p class="clJustify">This is text that should be jus-<br>&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="clJustify">tified and also hyphenated.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `text-align-last` is barely supported by newer browsers.

Comment: @Xufox Agreed, for now I have used `-ms-text-align-last` and the OP already uses the `:after` fix.

Comment: Well, thank you Praveen, this works in IE but not in FF or Chrome. 
Can you explain the `<br>&nbsp;`?

Comment: @MartinAuer To be frank, I have no clue. Just tried it before and it worked. Sorry I couldn't explain why. But it is because, it forces it not to be a last line. Remove the `br` may be?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, thank you for your effort, I really appreciate it, but I need a cross browser solution.