# What is text-align: justify-all?

Tags: html, css, w3c

In css what does the property `text-align: justify-all` do? On [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) they suggest it justifies the content of last line too. But I see nothing happening in my chrome browser:

```html
<p style="text-align: justify-all">
one two three four fiveone two three four fiveone two three four fiveone two three four fiveone two three four fiveone two three four fiveone two three four fiveone two three four fiveone two three four fiveone two three four fiveone two three four fiveone two three four fiveone two three four fiveone two three four five
</p>
```

Comment: Exactly, fails everywhere .... https://www.w3.org/International/tests/repo/results/text-align#justifyall

Comment: Maybe this is a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771304/justify-the-last-line-of-a-div

Answer (score 6):

Checking the W3C spec, it doesn't appear to be supported by any major browser https://www.w3.org/International/tests/repo/results/text-align.

You can try text-align-last. It does have browser support, but it's not great http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-text-align-last