# HTML CSS Text Align justify isn't working correctly

Tags: html, css, text-alignment, text-align

```html
        <table >
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="1">FrisBar:</th>
                    <th > <p style="color:#111;">00</p> </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Totaal:</p></td>
                    <td><p id="FrisBarTot1">0</p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Kratjes:</p></td>
                    <td><p id="FrisBarKrat1">0</p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Overige:</p></td>
                    <td><p id="FrisBarOver1">0</p></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The first two "totaal" and "Kratjes", are working fine but the "overige" isn't aligning how I want it.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

### Edit:

By using a table it works and making the two 00 in the  makes the numbers have an equal size/space.
I want to thank everyone who helped me:D

Comment: I put your code in a snippet in your question but note that you omitted a closing `}` in your CSS

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried to do it as good as possible. I must have missed that while copy pasting.

Comment: The text-align: justify will not justify the last line. Instead it will aligned left. You should use some trick to make the last line justified. For reference, try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771304/justify-the-last-line-of-a-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a table it works and making the two 00 in the second cell, makes the numbers have an equal size/space.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this.

```css
  #main {
  transition: margin-left 0.1s;
  padding: 16px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.mainText p {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="mainText">
  <p class="bartext" id="tabelFrisBar">Totaal: 0 Kratjes: 0 Overige: 0</p>
  <p class="bartext" id="tabelFrisExtra">Totaal: 0 Kratjes: 0 Overige: 0</p>
  <p class="bartext" id="tabelBierExtra">Totaal: 0 Kratjes: 0 Overige: 0</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using `inline-block` and based on your screenshot it looks like they should be blocks. Here is the code markup based on your screenshot:

```css
.bartext-container {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
  
.bartext {
  align-self: flex-start;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  width: auto;
  
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="mainText">
  <div class="bartext-container">
    <div class="bartext" id="tabelFrisBar">  
       Totaal: 0<br>
       Kratjes: 0<br>
       Overige: 0
    </div>
    <div class="bartext" id="tabelFrisBarExtra">  
       Totaal: 0<br>
       Kratjes: 0<br>
       Overige: 0
    </div>
    <div class="bartext" id="tabelFrisBarExtra">  
       Totaal: 0<br>
       Kratjes: 0<br>
       Overige: 0
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks good here, but when I copy it to my own code, It doenst work the trick.
I am working with a sidebar on my page, which re-adjusts the width.

Also, i would like the numbers to be aligned too.

Would i be better of by using a table and just align everything to the left?

Comment: can you share your full markup and css in a gist https://gist.github.com/?